# Problemas con la POKE API python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

Hola como va? Estoy tratando de que mi programa me genere un archivo .csv donde tenga 4 columnas ID, name, weight, height y base_hp de la lista de 1118 **pokemon** que hay en la poke api cuyo link es https://pokeapi.co/

Mi problema es que si yo quiero obtener la información de cada pokemon debo hacer un get de la api una vez por cada pokemon y esto me parece totalmente ineficiente. Igualmente probé generar una lista de todos los nombres y luego iterando dicha lista hacer un get por cada iteración pasando como parametro el nombre del pokemon e igualmente no logro que funcione. Según mi razonamiento creo que es correcto lo que estoy haciendo pero por alguna razon que no entiendo el programa no anda.

El error que me tira es lo cual no entiendo porque siendo un diccionario si yo le paso las llaves debería devolverme el contenido de cada llave.

```
poke_data['name'] = results['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Adjunto mi código y agradezco sujerencias.

```
from os import sep
import requests
from requests.models import ReadTimeoutError 
import csv

def first_scrap():
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"
    args = {'offset' : 0, 'limit' : 1118 }
    response = requests.get(url, params=args)
    name = []
    if response.status_code == 200:
        payload = response.json()
        results = payload.get("results", [])        
        if results:
            for pokemon in results:
                name.append(pokemon['name'])
        return name
    else:
        return 404

def scraping (id):
    args = {'offset' : 0, 'limit' : 1118 }
    response = requests.get(f"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{id}/", params= args)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        payload = response.json()
        results = payload.get("results", [])

        poke_data = {
                    'ID' : '',
                    'name': '',
                    'weight': '',
                    'height': '',
                    #'base_hp' : ''
                    }
        
        poke_data['name'] = results['name']
        poke_data['weight'] = results['weight']
        poke_data['height'] = results['height']
        #poke_data['base_hp'] = payload['base_hp']

        return poke_data

def execute ():
    names = first_scrap()
    headers = ['name', 'weight', 'height'] # I can't find the 'base_hp' detail in the API
    with open('pokemon_details.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=headers)
        writer.writeheader()

        for id in range(1, 1119):
            id = str(id)
            rows = scraping(id)
            writer.writerows(rows)


    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute()
```

Comment: Cual es el error que tienes?, tienes problemas al consultar los datos, al guardarlos? O que?

Comment: Perdon no especifique el problema! me dice poke_data['name'] = results['name']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str      lo cual no entiendo porq si yo tengo un diccionario y le paso las llaves me debería devolver correctamente lo que posee cada llave.

Comment: Una API REST según definición, debe devolverte, en el caso de un listado, un grupo de recursos que cumplen el filtro asociado. Luego, debes iterar por cada resultado para obtener los datos específicos de dicho elemento. Otra cosa muy distinta es lo que hacemos la mayoría(yo incluido) que devolvemos los datos en el propio listado, incumpliendo REST. Tu proceso debe primero buscar todos los Pokémon, leer cada uno de los recursos (URL del detalle del Pokémon) y leer uno a uno dichos recursos.